# Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sonarqube

```html
<div v-html="this.getNormalMessage()"></div>
```

We are using `"vue": "^2.5.17"`. While running a sonarqube report we got these hotspots "Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here." for the above code snippet. Using v-html is causing this hotspot in sonarqube report. `getNormalMessage` is function which returns htmlContent.

we tried the solutions like

```html
<div>{{ getNormalMessage }}</div>
```

but these solutions are converting content into a plain text. In our case we needed it to be rendered as html.
Do we have better solutions ?

Comment: Don't use `this` keyword and remove the parentheses. We're not able to help anymore because the question lacks of minimum information. Edit your question and add where `getNormalMessage` comes from.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, i have made changes in the question posted. Hope this conveys better information.

Comment: Can you also put the inner content of `getNormalMessage`?

Comment: Give a yr to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074884/8816585

Comment: I faced this error while using vue-dompurify-html.
```ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
error  in ./node_modules/vue-dompurify-html/dist/vue-dompurify-html.mjs
Can't import the named export 'isVue3' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```
I also found vue-html-secure package. this works fine without any issues.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-secure

Comment: Install that version of the package (compatible with Vue2): https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html/releases/tag/v2.5.2 It does have more downloads and is more well-known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074884/8816585), you can use  [vue-dompurify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dompurify-html).
Be careful, only the [`v2.5.2`](https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html/releases/tag/v2.5.2) has still Vue2 support, then [it's dropped](https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html/releases/tag/v3.0.0).